# Issue constructing post request in PowerShell v2

Tags: powershell, http, post, request

I want each of my number crunching nodes to periodically update my web server on the number of MATLAB instances it is running, so I'm trying to figure out how to construct an HTTP Post request with PowerShell v2. For technical reasons, I will NOT be able to use Powershell v3, so I can't use Invoke-WebRequest (aka curl). I found a script that's supposed to work with v2, but I'm not sure how to put the body of my request into the correct format.

Here is my PowerShell script (code was borrowed from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/powershell-script-to-send-8955b12e):

```
busy = (tasklist | findstr "MATLAB.exe" | measure).Count #Get number of MATLAB instances
postParams = @{busy=$busy}
$endPointURL = "http://10.1.10.153:8888/receiveStatus.php" 
$webRequest = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($endPointURL) 
Write-Host "Sending POST Request"+$endPointURL 
$webRequest.Timeout = 60000; 
$webRequest.ContentType="application/xml"; 
$webRequest.Method= 'POST'; 
$requestBody = $postParams
$Body = [byte[]][char[]]$requestBody;
$Stream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream();
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Char[]".
At C:\Users\boris\Desktop\050218_test3.ps1:15 char:1
+ $Body = [byte[]][char[]]$requestBody;
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

So can somebody please tell me the correct format in which to put my request body so that this error message disappears? Literally, I'm just trying to make it say something to the effect of `{'busy':'5'}` (if 5 is the number of MATLAB instances). I've tried googling it, but so far haven't found any good sources. No idea why, because this seems like it should be trivial.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either write it directly as a JSON string `$Body = "{'busy'='$busy'}"` or write it as a PowerShell hashtable and use the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet to turn it into a JSON hashtable in a string.